# Android: RecyclerView with Header and Footer; last item is never shows if there is the header

Tags: android, header, android-recyclerview

I've implemented this [class](https://github.com/u3breeze/android-RecyclerView-WithHeaderAndFooter/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/willfng/hfrvadapter/HFRecyclerViewAdapter.java) for adding header in my RecyclerView. It's work fine, but the last item in my list is never show if the header is present. If I remove the header is fine.

It's really strange because when I add a breakpoint in getItemCount(), it's never break.

Do you see a problem in this implementation?

Comment: please post your code...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a header and footer the getItemCount() method should return.

```
     mList.size()+2;
```

ie Your list size +1 for header and one for footer.

If you want only one then use

```
     mList.size()+1
```

If it doesnt work please show code so that i can debug better.